# How to get a rate of tapping in Praat?

Tags: rate, praat

I would like to get the rate of tapping (per sec) for woodpeckers recordings in Praat (example of rec below). I have been looking but could not find an easy command or script that would allow to get this info without annotation.

Is there a simple way for someone not used to script writing?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfuGO.png)

Comment: You may be able to use this script, which was made to measure syllables per second: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BRM.41.2.385.pdf
What it really does is detect amplitude peaks, so it may be able to detect the peaks in the waveform shown in the picture you posted.  I would advise you to low-pass filter your audios at around 2500Hz if this audio is typical, as the top half of the spectrograms looks very strange and that noise may impact the script.
The new version of this script also detects silences: https://sites.google.com/site/speechrate/Home/praat-script-syllable-nuclei

Answer (score 1):

You could use Pitch; 'Get pitch' (F5).
Pulses are often linked to periods to measure pitch, so that should work.

OR:
You can use Pulses; **Voice report** which gives you the number of pulses Praat measures in your selection. Simply dividing the number of pulses by the time of your selection would give you the rate. Example of a voice report:
[Voice Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG11P.png)